Why don't I get a choice of file systems when I burn a data dvd with brasero on 24.04?
Why don't I get a choice of file systems when I burn a data dvd with brasero on 24.04? Is there a default file system for DVD?

Globally, the standard for CDs is to use ISO9660 (aka CDFS) and its corresponding extensions, and for DVDs is to use UDF (Universal Disk Format).  That way it's readable on all systems.
If you are using CDs for data, your only real option of filesystem is ISO9660, as that's the global standard for CDs.
If you are using DVDs, your only real option of filesystem is UDF for universal compatibility per the standard for DVDs.
